# How to capture login event in Laravel Nova 4

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

I've been searching but couldn't find a solution.
I don't know if Nova allows it, but I need to save to a Log file every time a user accesses through the Login screen.

Comment: you can directly use laravel Auth login event https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/events#writing-event-subscribers

Answer (score 0):

goto `Http/Controllers/Auth/LoginController.php` and you can write your code in `login` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can override nova login controller in `NovaServiceProvider`

```
public function boot()
{
    parent::boot();

    $this->app->alias(
        \App\Http\Controllers\Nova\LoginController::class,
        \Laravel\Nova\Http\Controllers\LoginController::class
    );
}
```

And add custom logic to new `LoginController`